# Solving $\phi(n)=84$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Ok, I really need some help understanding this because either my brain isn't working at the moment or I'm breaking math and I have a striking suspicion that one of those is more likely.

Anyways, here's my process. WolframAlpha tells me there are 12 integer solutions, they are all $^+_-n$ so let's say there are 6 of them. They are as follows: $129, 147, 172, 196, 258, 294$

Ok, so here's how I attempted to solve it. $n$ looks like this ${\prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{\alpha_i}}$. And $\phi(n)=n\prod_{p\vert n}(1-\frac{1}{p})$. So I plug $n$ in and get an equation like this:

$\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{\alpha_i-1}(p_i-1)=84$

Now, solving for $n$ SHOULD be equivalent to solving for $p_i, \alpha_i$, right?

So, I started going through possible values of $k$ and I'm interested in the case of $k=2$.

This means that $n$ has two prime factors, so it looks like $p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}$, and the equation is:

$p_1^{\alpha_1-1}(p_1-1)p_2^{\alpha_2-1}(p_2-1)=84$

Ok. Here's my issue. Factoring $84$, we get $2\times2\times3\times7$

So I try to see a pattern. The first solution I came up with is $p_1=7, \alpha_1=2, p_2=2, \alpha_2=2$. Then I followed the same logic that led me to that solution but didn't find any more so I concluded that the other solutions must be as higher values of $k$. But then I factored $172$ and saw that it also had only two primes. It also fits the pattern. So I realized that I could get ones in that product as a result of $p^0$ and following that pattern, filling in the remaining factors, I found the $129$ solution.

No more, the next one must be at $k=3$. NOPE. $147$ also factors into only 2 primes. So now I'm really at a miss. Is there a more effective way to iterate over all of these combinations?

Comment: If you break math, I'll be quite sad.

Comment: Not only will naslundx be sad if you break math: you will have to pay for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at 7. Two possibilities:

- $7|(p-1)$ with $p|n$:
  hence $p = 14k+1 \in \{ 29, 43\}$ (the others are too big).
- If $p=29$, $\phi(n) = 28\times 3 = (29-1)(3)$. 3 has to be some $(p-1)p^{a-1}$ but $p=4$ is not prime.
- If $p=43$, you have the solution $\phi(n) = 42\times 2\implies n = 43\times 3$ or
  $n = 43\times 2^2$.
- Otherwise: $7|n$. $\phi(n) = 6\times 7\times 2\implies n= 7^2\times 3$ or $n= 7^2\times 2^2$.

I have used that $\phi(n) = 2\implies n\in\{3,4\}$.

Comment: yes, it is $\phi(n)=2\implies\dots$ and not 3. This is what the reader sould understand if he reads the preceeding computation.

Comment: I'm confused by the first implication. If $7\vert(p-1)$ then $p=7k+1$. Now, how does $p\vert n$ imply $p=14k+1$?

Comment: $p$ is a prime, it is not 2 hence it has to be odd.

Answer (score 1):

```
  84         129 = 3 * 43
  84         147 = 3 * 7^2
  84         172 = 2^2 * 43
  84         196 = 2^2 * 7^2
  84         258 = 2 * 3 * 43
  84         294 = 2 * 3 * 7^2
```

I see, you had those.

I suppose what I would emphasize is this: $\phi$ is multiplicative. So it is determined by its behavior on prime powers. Next, $\phi (p^k)$ is always divisible by $p-1.$ So, we are required to have $(p-1) | 84,$  so out of that list of numbers with $\phi(n) | 84,$

```
   1           2 = 2
   2           3 = 3
   2           4 = 2^2
   4           5 = 5
   2           6 = 2 * 3
   6           7 = 7
   4           8 = 2^3
   6           9 = 3^2
   4          10 = 2 * 5
   4          12 = 2^2 * 3
  12          13 = 13
   6          14 = 2 * 7
   6          18 = 2 * 3^2
  12          21 = 3 * 7
  12          26 = 2 * 13
  12          28 = 2^2 * 7
  28          29 = 29
  12          36 = 2^2 * 3^2
  12          42 = 2 * 3 * 7
  42          43 = 43
  42          49 = 7^2
  28          58 = 2 * 29
  42          86 = 2 * 43
  42          98 = 2 * 7^2
  84         129 = 3 * 43
  84         147 = 3 * 7^2
  84         172 = 2^2 * 43
  84         196 = 2^2 * 7^2
  84         258 = 2 * 3 * 43
  84         294 = 2 * 3 * 7^2
```

the primes allowed are 2,3,5,7,13,29,43, I guess that's it. Some evident prime powers that need to be considered as alternatives to just primes. Oh, 13 does not get used, because then you need $\phi(something) = 21,$ and $\phi$ is never odd unless it is exactly $1.$ Again, 9 does not get used, i don't think there is any number with $\phi = 14,$ don't remember why, but people ask that here fairly often so you can [find an answer on MSE.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5661/generalizing-values-which-eulers-totient-function-does-not-take). The bit about odd is fairly easy, if there is any odd prime factor $p,$  then $(p-1)$ is even. So all that is left is powers of $2.$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a technique you can use to solve these kinds of problems that doesn't need much intuition. Firstly, you need a lemma.

**Lemma**: If $n$ is odd, then $\phi(n) =\phi(2n)$.

If the prime factorisation of $n$ is $n = \prod_{i=1}^m p_i^{\alpha_i}$, then $\phi(n) = \prod_{i=1}^m p_i^{\alpha_i-1}(p_i-1)$. So $p_i - 1 \mid 84$. Listing out factors of 84, the possible values $p_i-1$ can take are:

$$p_i-1 = 1,2,4,6,7,12,14,21,42,84.$$

Then,
$$p_i = 2,3,5,7,8,13,15,22,43,85,$$ of which $8,15,22,85$ are not prime. So possible values of $p_i$ can take are:
$$p_i = 2,3,5,7,13,43.$$

Now condition on the highest prime occurring in the prime factorisation of $n$.

$43$ is the highest prime dividing $n$: Then $\phi(n) = 42*a, a=2$. Then we only need to hunt for something to contribute a factor of $2$ for $\phi(n)$. This can come from $2^2$ or $3$. This gives $n = 43*3$ or $n=43*2^2$ respectively. With the lemma, $\phi(2*43*3)=\phi(3*43)$. This gives $3$ solutions, $n= 129,258,172$.

$13$ is the highest prime dividing $n$. $\phi(n) = 12 *a , a=7$. We need to hunt for a term contributing $7$. $7$ can either come from one of the $p_i-1$'s or $p_i$'s. It is the latter because $p_i-1 = 7 \implies p_i = 8$, which is not prime. Yet, having $7 \mid n$ would imply $6 *12 \mid \phi(n)$, contradiction. So $13$ cannot be the highest prime dividing $n$.

$7$ is the highest prime dividing $n$. $\phi(n) = 6*a, a=14$. We need to hunt for a term contributing $14$. Yet all primes dividing $n$ are going to be smaller than $7$ already, so the only option for $\phi(n)$ to incur a factor of $7$ would be for the power of $7$ in the prime factorisation of $n$ to be $\geq 2$. We can further see that it has to be exactly $2$. This means that $7^2 \mid n$ and $\phi(n) = 7*6*a, a=2$. We still need a factor of $2$, which would come from $3$ or $2^2$. So $n = 7^2 * 3$ or $n = 7^2 * 2^2$. From the lemma, $n = 2*7^2 *3$ is a viable option as well. So $n = 147,294, 196$.

$5$ is the highest prime dividing $n$. Then we need to hunt for a term contributing $21$. Yet this implies $7 \mid n$, but now the primes are too `small' to contribute a $7$, contradiction.

Similarly, for $3$ and $2$ being the highest prime dividing $n$, it will always imply that $7 \mid n$. So there are no more answers.