# Find all values of N that satisfy ϕ(N) = x for any given x value

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, totient-function

How would I determine all values of n in ϕ(n) = x for any value of x where ϕ is Euler's totient function? (and -1 if x is not a totient). Is there a simple formula for this? Or is this a lot more complicated than I think this is? Simply trying every number from x + 1 to the upper limit is too inefficient. I will be using numbers up to 1,000,000,000,000, so efficiency is key here.

Comment: Seems like the latter ... see e. g. [here](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEIQFjAEahUKEwjJ8fOW4c7IAhUE8HIKHcO4AT4&url=http%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F1401.6054&usg=AFQjCNFbmjnrU9tDNWVrtR6MEIxUhpC44Q&sig2=uWCEFwvI3yVSPFIUkVH6Eg&bvm=bv.105454873,d.bGQ)

Comment: You may find some idea how to do this for some given $x$ from various older posts on this site. For example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126844/eulers-function-phi-values-such-that-phin-8-phin-14 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761014/solving-phin-84 (And a few more posts are linked in the sidebar among related questions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper below proves that it is very unlikely that this problem can be solved efficiently:

> "Complexity of Inverting the Euler Function" by Scott Contini, Ernie Croot and Igor E. Shparlinski, published in *Mathematics of Computation* ([doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-06-01826-6), [arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404116))