# Is Euler's totient function surjective?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function, coprime

I other words can I find a number m for any number $n$ such that $\varphi(m)=n$?

It would be great if you could also present a proof or a link to a paper that contains a proof

Edited note: I forgot to mention $n$ must be even as $\varphi(m)$ is always even.

Comment: Literally the first related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5661/259363) discusses it...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generalizing values which Euler's-totient function does not take](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5661/generalizing-values-which-eulers-totient-function-does-not-take)

Comment: $\varphi(m)$ is not always even. But only for $m=1$ and $m=2$ it is odd with value $1$. The even numbers that are not included are also called "non-totients". There are infinite many of them.

Answer (score 2):

For all $m\geq3$ the number $\varphi(m)$ is even:

For every integer $a$ we have $\gcd(a,m)=\gcd(m-a,m)=1$, and $a\neq m-a$ unless $m=2a$, so $\varphi(m)$ is even if $m$ is odd. If $m=4k+2$ then
$$\varphi(m)=\varphi(4k+2)=\varphi(2)\varphi(2k+1)=\varphi(2k+1),$$
which is again odd, and of course if $m=4k$ then $\varphi(m)=\varphi(4k)$ is even.

Also not every *even* number $n$ is of the form $n=\varphi(m)$, for example $n=14$:

Suppose $\varphi(m)=14$. If $m$ is a prime power, say $m=p^k$, then
$$\varphi(m)=\varphi(p^k)=p^{k-1}(p-1).$$
Clearly $k>1$ because $15$ is not prime, so $p=2$ or $p=7$. If $p=2$ then $14=\varphi(m)=2^{k-1}$, a contradiction. If $p=7$ then $14=7^{k-1}\cdot6$, a contradiction. So $m$ is not a prime power; let $a>b>1$ be coprime integers such that $m=ab$. Then
$$2\cdot7=14=\varphi(m)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b),$$
so one of $\varphi(a)$ or $\varphi(b)$ is odd; because $b<a$ it follows that $b=2$ and hence $\varphi(b)=1$ and $\varphi(a)=14$ with $a$ odd. Now by the exact same argument we find that $a=cd$ with $c>d>1$ coprime, and hence $d=2$; a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

No. A natural number which is not in the range of the totient function is called a [nontotient](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontotient). The smallest even nontotient is $14$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/754043) for a proof. (Edit: or Servaes's nice answer!)